# Why is .getChildCount() always zero for my ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView`, declared as:

```
private ExpandableListView mELV_PredefinedFruit;
```

and uses an adapter which `extends` `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.  It displays onscreen correctly with various children in 2 groups (both expanded). 
 However I always get zero which I check the number of children at the end of 
the `Activity` `onCreate` using the following:

```
int numberOfChildViews = mELV_PredefinedFruit.getChildCount();
Log.d(LOG_CLASS, String.format(Locale.US, "%s number of child views in ELV:  %d", METHOD, numberOfChildViews));
```

Why is it always zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 0, because your view is not yet ready.
Try this:

```
mELV_PredefinedFruit.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int numberOfChildViews = mELV_PredefinedFruit.getChildCount();
        Log.d(LOG_CLASS, String.format(Locale.US, "%s number of child views in ELV:  %d", METHOD, numberOfChildViews));
    }
});
```